# R: Logical operations on two columns accounting for presence of NA in both

Tags: r, logical-operators

I have this data frame with two columns which can either take the value of `left` or `right`.

```
test_df <- data.frame(col1 = c("right","left","right",NA),
                      col2 = c("left","right",NA,"right"))

test_df

#    col1  col2
# 1 right  left
# 2  left right
# 3 right  <NA>
# 4  <NA> right
```

Now I want to test this multiple condition

```
test_df$col1 == "left" | test_df$col2 == "right"

# [1] FALSE  TRUE    NA  TRUE
```

The first three results are as expected, but why the last result is `TRUE` instead of `NA`. What's different between results for row 3 and row 4?

Comment: @RHertel How do I ask R to check for both conditions before returning, and returning NA when either one is NA?

Comment: For completeness and better visibility for other readers, I have posted my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are testing whether at least one of the following conditions is fulfilled; "left" in col1 or "right" in col2. In row 4 you have "right" in col2, therefore the result is `TRUE`, irrespective of what may or may not be in col1. The situation is different in row 3. There, col1 does not contain "left", hence it remains to be seen if col2 contains "right" in order to conclude whether the statement is `FALSE` or `TRUE`. However, since the entry in col2 for row 3 is `NA`, the result of the comparison cannot be decided and, accordingly, the output is `NA`.

If you want to have a function that performs the comparison between the entries in col1 and col2 that you mentioned but returns `NA` if *any* of the entries in those two columns is `NA`, you could use

```
as.logical((test_df$col1 == "left") + (test_df$col2 == "right"))
#[1] FALSE  TRUE    NA    NA
```

In this line of code, the results of the individual comparisons, yielding `TRUE` or `FALSE`, are coerced into numerical values by the `+` operator. If any part of the sum is `NA`, the sum will be `NA`. This addition is done for each row of the dataframe, so the result is a vector with the length `nrow(test_df)`.

By using `as.logical()`, the result of the sum calculated in the brackets is converted back into logical values. Again, this is done for each element of the vector. If the sum is zero, then the result is `FALSE`, if it is `NA` it will remain `NA`. Any non-zero integer will be converted into `TRUE`.